# UIImagePickerController causing crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using ios 8.4. When debugging an app, and I present a UIImagePickerController, xcode loses connection with the iphone. This wasn't a problem before.

Sometimes it will bring up the image picker... but then when I save an image, there'll be a crash.

Is anyone else experiencing this? How to fix?

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.editing = NO;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls=YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Add some code in your question.

Comment: why cast self to (id) on line 4? is your viewController a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

Comment: you're right. i don't need that.

Comment: Add details about your crash. What's the error? Which line of code is causing the crash?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
- (IBAction)galleryButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
  UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    pickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  if (image == nil)
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  // Do something with the image
  [self.imageView setImage:image];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```